# Which of the following is an invalid path for the following graph?

Tags: data-structures, graph, directed-graph

[Directed graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mByDL.png)

Which of the following is an invalid path for the following graph?
A. CBA
B. CDEFG
C. CDACBA
D. CDA

I'm learning about graphs in data structure and I don't really understand why there is an invalid path among these options. Can anyone please explain? Thank you so much!

Comment: First of all welcome to stackoverflow! The 4 options that you gave are actually all examples of valid paths in the graph. An invalid path in this graph would look something like DCB or FED.

Comment: I just looked at the quiz where this question came from and it seems like they are defining an "invalid" path when we have some kind of cycle in our path. So C is the "invalid" path. I hope that this helps :)

Comment: I've got it. Thank you!